# Image is not fetching from database

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, uiimageview, exc-bad-access

I stored some images in my server. I used JSON for fetch remote data from server. When i was storing images in local database it was working. When i use json url it's not working. Im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

code:

Mysof.h file:

```
@interface Mysof : NSObject{
    NSInteger sofaId;
    NSString *sofa;
    NSString *rating;
    UIImage *photo;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *sofa;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger sofaId;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *photo;

@end
```

Mysof.m file:

```
@implementation Mysof

@synthesize sofId;
@synthesize sofa;
@synthesize rating;
@synthesize photo;

@end
```

Sofalistsql.h file:

```
@interface Sofalistsql : NSObject

{
    sqlite3 *db;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) getMysofas;

@end
```

.m file:

```
 @implementation Sofalistsql

    - (NSMutableArray *) getMysofas{


     NSMutableArray *sofArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *err;

    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Empty" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"bundlePath %@", bundlePath);


    //call update function to check any data updated,
    //if there is a version difference
    //update the data base with all the required fileds.



    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", documentsDirectory);

    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"App6.sqlite"];

    [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];


    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.net/projects/mobile/jsonstring.php"];

    NSLog(@"URL is %@", URL);


     NSError *error;
     NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
     initWithContentsOfURL:URL
     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
     error:&error];

     //NSLog(@"response is %@", stringFromFileAtURL);

     NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"App6.sqlite"];


     NSArray *userData = [stringFromFileAtURL JSONValue];

     // NSArray *skarray = [[NSArray alloc]init];



    NSLog(@"userdata is %@", userData);

   // int  i = 0;
    BOOL notExist = TRUE;


     for (NSArray *skarray in userData) {

     for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {


           //if already exists in data base id then overwrite the name 

         if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {


      const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM categories where id = '%@'",[tuser objectForKey:@"id"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     

     //NSLog(@"check stmt is %s", sql);

     sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement,*addStmt;

     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

       notExist = TRUE;

     while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        notExist = FALSE;


     Mysof *Mylist = [[Mysof alloc]init];
     Mylist.sofaId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
     Mylist.sofa = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
     Mylist.rating = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
     const char *raw = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 3);
     int rawLen = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 3);
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:raw length:rawLen];
     Mylist.photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
     [sofArray addObject:Mylist];



     }

         if(notExist){
             //NSLog(@"cat id does not exist");

             const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into categories (id, cat_name,order_by) values ('%@', '%@', '%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"id"], [tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"],[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             //NSLog(@"stmt is %s", sqlInsert);

             if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                 NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

             if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                 NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

         }


     }

     }

     }

     }

    return sofArray;


}

   @end
```

In viewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    Sofalistsql * mysofs =[[Sofalistsql alloc] init];
    self.sofas = [mysofs getMysofas];



}
```

Button click to display images from server:

```
-(void)click:(id)sender{


 scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,500,320,200)];

        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
          scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;

      scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

        int Width = 0;      

     //   Width = Width + 20+(i*74);


  for (int i = 0; i<[self.sofas count]; i++ ) {
            NSLog(@"index %d",i);



          //  imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 500, 72, 72)];

            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

            Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

            [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [imgView1 setImage:((Mysof *)[self.sofas objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

          //  [myScroll addSubview:imgView1];



        }

        [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Width,imgView1.frame.size.height+20)];

        [self.view addSubview:scrollview];



}
```

jsonstring.php file:

```
<?php 
    require_once('database_connection.php');
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $k = 0;
    $l = 0;
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8') or die("MYSQL character set error: ".mysql_error());
    $result = array();
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $result[0][$i] = $res;

                $art_sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id=" .$res['id']. " ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($art_sql) > 0){
                    while($art_res=mysql_fetch_array($art_sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                        //$art_res['art_details'] = (utf8_encode(htmlentities($art_res['art_details'])));
                        //$art_res['art_details'] = htmlentities($art_res['art_details']);
                        //echo $art_res['art_details'];
                        $result[1][$k] = $art_res;
                        //print_r($art_res);    
                        $k = $k+1;  
                    }   
                }
                $i= $i+1;
            }
            $version_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM version_app order by product_id desc limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($version_sql);
            $last_version = $row['product_id'];
            $result['2'][$l] = array('product_id' => $last_version);
            $l = $l+1;
        }


        /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";exit;*/

    $str_enc = json_encode($result);
    //print_r($str_enc); exit;
    $str=str_replace('\r','',$str_enc);
    $str=str_replace('\t','',$str);
    $str=str_replace('\n','',$str);
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    //$str_renc = json_encode(json_decode($str));

    echo $str;

mysql_close();
?>
```

NSLog:

```
userdata is (
        (
                {
            "cat_name" = Table1;
            id = 1;
            "order_by" = 1;
        },
                {
            "cat_name" = Table2;
            id = 2;
            "order_by" = 2;
        },
                {
            "cat_name" = test;
            id = 3;
            "order_by" = 3;
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 2;
            "order_by" = 1;
            "product_image" = "img.png";
        },
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 3;
            "order_by" = 2;
            "product_image" = "img1.png";
        },
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 4;
            "order_by" = 3;
            "product_image" = "img2.png";
        },
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 5;
            "order_by" = 4;
            "product_image" = "img3.png";
        },
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 6;
            "order_by" = 5;
            "product_image" = "img4.png";
        },
                {
            "cat_id" = 1;
            id = 7;
            "order_by" = 6;
            "product_image" = "img5.png";
        },

    )
)


array (
)
2013-08-16 13:19:53.044 App[3395:c07] scroll is <UIScrollView: 0x9de7cb0; frame = (0 300; 320 200); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9de60e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9de4bc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

I stored same Table name in local database. And used overwrite database. In local database i stored images in `BLOB` type. But in my array i got nothing displaying. App is working. But images are not displaying from database.

Comment: First thing you are not passing mutableArray from getMysofas method. second why you are initailizing scrollview twice, once in viewDidLoad and other on click action. Its very difficult to go through entire code and find where is the problem, can you please debug and show where it is actually crashing. By error it means that it is some memory issue, you are trying to access some object which is already released.

Comment: Im using ARC. So i comment release in JSON file. IS it causing error?

Comment: How to pass mutuableArray from getMySofas method?

Comment: Call return sofArray , at the end of your method. The file you are showing is not json file, its php code. Json file contains key-value pair.

Comment: I copied JSON framework into my folder. And added JSON.h in viewcontroller.m file

Comment: return sofArray is working. But images are not displaying from server. Is objectForKey:@"id" is correct?

Comment: BTW, do I infer from `retain` and `assign` property attributes that this is MRC code? If so, run it through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu), as I see some leaks here which the analyzer would identify and you could easily fix.

Comment: @user2674668 can you us some of your raw JSON data as a string, so we an diagnose what's going on?

Comment: @Rob: Can you check my edited code

Comment: @user2674668 Looking at your JSON, I see a bit of a structural disconnect, that your JSON is an array of three arrays, each of which has a different dictionary structure. First, that's simply a strange JSON representation (arrays are for homogeneous items). Second, your Objective-C code doesn't match the JSON generated by your PHP code. See my revised answer for a discussion about that.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've included your JSON sample, I can see another problem: Your JSON is an array of three arrays, an array of categories, an array of products, and an array of versions. That is a questionable structure (usually an array would be of homogeneous items of the same type). Rather than an array of arrays, I'd make it a dictionary of arrays.

This confusing structure in your JSON manifests itself in your Objective-C code. You're trying to iterate through the `userdata` array, but you can't, because each of the three item is different.

So let me suggest two possible fixes. First you if you stick with your array of arrays (which I'm not crazy about), you cannot iterate through that array with a `for` loop, but you could extract the three arrays it contains like so:

```
NSArray *categories = userdata[0];
NSArray *products = userdata[1];
NSArray *versions = userdata[2];
```

Now you can iterate through each of those three arrays.

Personally, I'd take this a step further and change that PHP that generates the JSON to generate a top level dictionary, e.g.

```
<?php 
    require_once('database_connection.php');
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $k = 0;
    $l = 0;
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8') or die("MYSQL character set error: ".mysql_error());
    $result = array();
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $result['categories'][$i] = $res;

                $art_sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id=" .$res['id']. " ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($art_sql) > 0){
                    while($art_res=mysql_fetch_array($art_sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                        $result['products'][$k] = $art_res;
                        $k = $k+1;  
                    }   
                }
                $i= $i+1;
            }
            $version_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM version_app order by product_id desc limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($version_sql);
            $last_version = $row['product_id'];
            $result['versions'][$l] = array('product_id' => $last_version);
            $l = $l+1;
        }

    $str_enc = json_encode($result);

    // note, these str_replace lines are not needed

    // $str=str_replace('\r','',$str_enc);
    // $str=str_replace('\t','',$str);
    // $str=str_replace('\n','',$str);

    // this stripslashes is a really bad idea, though

    // $str = stripslashes($str);

    // you echoed `$str`, but I'll obviously echo @str_enc    
    echo $str_enc;

    mysql_close();
?>
```

And if you did that, you could then retrieve your three arrays with

```
NSArray *categories = userdata[@"categories"];
NSArray *products = userdata[@"products"];
NSArray *versions = userdata[@"versions"];
```

It's not a mission critical change, but it's a more logical representation for three heterogeneous items. But the idea is the same: Extract your three arrays from your JSON, and now you can iterate through them, respectively.

---

A couple of SQLite-related issues leap out at me

1. One issue is that you have a line of SQL that says:

   ```
   SELECT id FROM categories where cat_id = '%@'
   ```

   But you then proceed to try to read four columns worth of data (even though you only returned one). And even if you changed your SQL to actually return four columns of data, you should really check the `sqlite3_column_blob` and `sqlite3_column_bytes` calls to make sure there was something to populate the `NSData`.

   As an aside, it's generally safer to not use `stringWithFormat` when building a SQL statement, but rather use `?` placeholders instead of printf-formatters and then use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.
2. You `getMysofas` is repeatedly opening the database, but never closing it. Have one `sqlite3_close` for every `sqlite3_open` call. Likewise, you should have one `sqlite3_finalize` statement for each `sqlite3_prepare_v2` line.

---

Beyond that you have to identify the source of the crash by either using an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), single-stepping through this code in the debugger, or putting a bunch of `NSLog` statements in there. See Ray Wenderlich's series [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1). But you really need to identify the line of code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I stored same Table name in local database. And used overwrite database. In local database i stored images in `BLOB` type. But in my array i got nothing displaying. App is working. But images are not displaying from database.

Comment: @user2674668 And did you fix the SQL (my first point)? Your SELECT statement does not retrieve the image data, and thus your calls to `sqlite3_column_bytes` and `sqlite3_column_blob` will fail.

Comment: @user2674668 We should move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35674/image-is-not-fetching-from-database